# Find all real values of $x, y$ and $z$ such that $x-\sqrt{yz}=42$, $y-\sqrt{xz}=6,z-\sqrt{xy}=-30$. (COMC) 1997 Part B Question 4

Tags: contest-math, radicals

Find all real values of $x, y$ and $z$ such that $x-\sqrt{yz}=42$, $y-\sqrt{xz}=6,z-\sqrt{xy}=-30$.

I was preparing for my COMC Contest so I was doing past years exams. This question really stop me so I want to get some help from others.

I tried substitute $x$ to $a^2$, $y$ to $b^2$ and $z$ to $c^2$. And combining the equations so I can turn this function to 2 variables. But I am stuck because I can't find a way of turning this function to 2 variables. I add the three new equations with a, b and c in pairs, but I can't reduce the equations to 2 variables. I also tried to subtract the equations in pairs, too. I still can't figure it out. Can someone solve my question with the same method too?

Thank you very much!

This question is from Canadian Open Mathematic Challenge (COMC) 1997 Part B Question 4.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I am a new contributor so if there is anything goes wrong I am sorry.

Comment: And one question how to change the question?

Comment: Click the [edit] button.

Comment: And you're welcome :)

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Again, you're welcome; for future reference: [here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: It's close enough, @Peter.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha [finds a solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x-sqrt%28y*z%29%3D42%2Cy-sqrt%28x*z%29%3D6%2C+z-sqrt%28x*y%29%3D-30).

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  Right you are.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for all your guys' help! You guys are awesome!

Comment: Thank you so much @Shaun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your substitution and subtracting the equations pairwise, we end up with:

$72 =  42 - (-30) = a^2 - bc - (c^2 - ab ) = (a-c) ( a+b+c)$
$36 = 6 - (-30) = b^2 - ca - (c^2 - ab) = (b-c) (a+b+c )$
$ 36 = 42 - 6 = a^2 - bc - (b^2 - ca) = (a-b) ( a + b + c) $

Hence $ a-c = 2 (b-c) = 2(a-b)$, or that $ b = \frac{ a+c}{2}$.
Substituting this into the second equation gives us $(a-c)^2 = 24 $ so $|a-c| = 2 \sqrt{6} $.
Substituting this into the first equation gives us $84 = 2a^2 - ac - c^2 = (a-c)(2a + c) $, so $ |2a+c| = 7 \sqrt{6} $, where $a-c, 2a+c$ have the same sign.

Hence, the solutions are $(a, b, c) = \pm ( 3 \sqrt{6}, 2 \sqrt{6}, \sqrt{6} )$, which gives us $ (x,y,z) = (54, 24, 6 )$.

---

Notes:

- Given the symmetry in the equations, taking the pairwise difference and (attempting to) factoring out $a-b$ is a common approach. It is often harder to work with the pairwise sum.

Comment: Thank you very much! I learned a lot from that!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach you may find useful. First of course set $x=a^2, y=b^2, z=c^2$ and the system reads
\begin{align}
&a^2-bc=42\\
&b^2-ac=6\\
&c^2-ab=-30\\
\end{align}
Now take the linear combination $(1)c+(2)a+(3)b$. We notice that the sum of the LHS is zero and hence we have found a simpler linear relation
$$42c+6a-30b=0$$
Taking a different linear combination $b(1)+c(2)+a(3)$ gives zero again when we add the LHS and therefore we get another linear relation.
$$42b+6c-30a=0$$
Solving the last two linear equations for $a,b$ in terms of $c$ we obtain the extremely simple relations
$$b=2c~,~ a=3c$$
and now substituting back into our original system we obtain $c^2=6$. All in all, the solutions are
$$(a,b,c)=\{(3\sqrt{6}, 2\sqrt{6}, \sqrt{6}),-(3\sqrt{6}, 2\sqrt{6}, \sqrt{6})\}$$
and for the solution of the original system, the second one cannot create a solution, while the first one generates the only solution
$$(x,y,z)=(54,24,6)$$
In such systems we see that it can be useful to find derivative quantities that are simpler than the ones contained in the original system. This system of equations has a high degree of symmetry on the LHS, so one should take advantage of that.

Comment: Thank you very much! I learned a lot from that!